# Getting certificate error on ubuntu 16.04 LTS for https://github.com

Tags: github

I am not able to access https://github.com from both browser and console after I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I open https://github.com from browser, I get "Your connection is not private" error. From the information provided on ADVANCED tab and by googling the reason I came to know this is due to client (My machine) could not verify the certificate provided by github.com.

I don't know how to update CA chain certificate in Ubuntu to get access to github.com

Comment: Maybe your system time is incorrect. I can access to github.

Comment: Check your system clock - it's usually the first culprit of something like this when it's way off the actual time